# readFrame failed to read Frames from video in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, frame

I want to read frames from a video and save each frame. But the readFrame failed to read the frames from the video. Somebody could help? Why does it not work?

```
clear all
close all
clc
tic
Video1 = VideoReader('D:\ywa\Matlab\experiment_3\b8_a4\hell\b8_a4_hell.mp4');
k = 1;
% frames = read(Video1,[5 10]);
while hasFrame(Video1)
    tmp = readFrame(Video1);
     frames(:,:,:,k) = tmp;
    k = k+1;
end
```

There are 70 frames in the video and the resolution is 3840*2160.
Many thanks. It seems that the while-loop dose not run in the code.

Comment: "failed" meaning...what?

Comment: Computer explodes? It gives you decimals of pi? You have no MATLAB license? there are a lot of explanations of "failed"!

Comment: When I run the code, there is no error,but it seems that the while-loop dose not work. frames are not loaded.

Comment: "Seems" how? Is `frames` empty? Nonexistent? Both the value of `k` and whether or not `frames` exists after you run your code should tell you whether or not it worked.

Comment: frames is not empty. I tried to extract the frames from this video with  ffmpeg. It worked and the frame is not empty. But when i run this in matlab, the frames could not be read

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you on? Windows 7 does not natively support reading UHD. This would indicate that you probably have installed additional codecs to read the video which might be the issue.

If on Windows 10, it should work fine.

Dinesh